# Is there an analogy for 'pangs of hunger' when it comes to thirst?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Does this sentence make sense?

*He was struck with pangs of thirst.*

Or is there a different word (specifically a noun that replaces *pangs*) that makes more sense in this context?

Comment: As you used a phrase in your title, allow phrases please in your answer.  Also, show your own research please.

Comment: For showing my own research, I tried googling (I first asked myself this question a few days ago and tried to find the answer) but searching for combinations of the words "pangs" and "thirst", all that came up was advice on how the body misinterprets thirst as hunger.

I searched further for another noun that describes a sudden feeling of thirst, but most of what I found was irrelevant.

After that, I knew that this site existed so I figured it might be a good next step.  If this is insufficient, I welcome any advice on how I *ought* to have proceeded.

Comment: "pangs of thirst" seems [common enough](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pangs+of+thirst%22&tbm=bks&ei=ulqiW4TfAqWBgAbm8rPIBg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1563&bih=701&dpr=1.75). And the definition of _pang_ clearly allows for this usage. Sure, _pangs_ are more commonly _of hunger_ (or _disappointment_ or _regret_ maybe) but not sure why you'd think _pangs of thirst_ wasn't OK. Go for it, say I.

Comment: "parched with thirst" is more common than pangs of thirst, which I don't think I've ever heard before.

Comment: @tmgr - I'm embarassed to say I never thought of using quotation marks in my google search.  I learned something new -- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for a noun, I did a Google Ngram search for [`*_NOUN of thirst`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_NOUN+of+thirst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsensation_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdegree_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpangs_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagonies_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfeeling_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btorments_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagony_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsence_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpain_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsense_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsensation_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdegree_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpangs_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bagonies_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfeeling_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btorments_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bagony_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Babsence_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpain_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsense_NOUN%20of%20thirst%3B%2Cc0) and got this:

> [image]

As you can see, "pangs of thirst" is used and it's the third most popular noun that can be used in this position (when you exclude "absence" and "sense", which obviously aren't relevant here). "Sensation" and "feeling", despite being more popular are... somewhat dry... so I'd prefer "pangs".

Answer (score 1):

**yearn**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/yearn)

n.

> A persistent, often melancholy desire; a longing:

As in:

> The sailors at sea yearned for water.

and

> ... he yearned for water.

Pangs of thirst is good too!
So is to crave for water.

Comment: Thanks!  So if I specifically wanted to use a noun, *pang* or *pangs* would be my best bet?